# Нажатие на отфильтрованный RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, cardview

Здравствуйте!
Я пытаюсь релизовать поиск в `RecyclerView` с помощью `SearchView`.
Всё работает хорошо, но мне нужно обрабатывать нажатие на отфильтрованный список, и я не знаю как это реализовать.

Код `card_view.xml:`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_shop_radius">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/shop_cover_height"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/thumbnail"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/shop_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/shop_title_padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/shop_title_padding"
                android:textColor="@color/shop_title"
                android:textSize="@dimen/shop_title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/distance"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/title"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/distance_padding_bottom"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/shop_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/shop_title_padding"
                android:textSize="@dimen/distance" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Код модели `YarObject:`

```
public class YarObject {
    private String name;
    private double distance;
    private int image;

    public YarObject() {}

    public YaroslavlObject(String name, double distance, int image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.distance = distance;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(double distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Код `RecyclerAdapter`:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShopsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<YarObject> objectList;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context mContext, List<YarObject> objectList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.objectList = objectList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.shop_card, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        YarObject object = objectList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(object.getName());
        holder.distance.setText(object.getDistance() + " км");

        Glide.with(mContext).load(object.getImage())
                            .into(holder.image);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return objectList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title, distance;
        ImageView image;
        CardView cardView;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            distance = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.distance);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        }
    }

    public void setFilter(List<YarObject> newList) {
        objectList = new ArrayList<>();
        objectList.addAll(newList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

В `MainActivity` я реализовал интерфейс `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`:

```
public class MainActivity extends MenuObjectsActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private RecyclerAdapter adapter;
    private List<YarObject> objectList;

    @SuppressLint("PrivateResource")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shops);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if (toolbar != null) {
            toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
            toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            });
        }

        initCollapsingToolbar();

        RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        objectList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, objectList);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        if (mRecyclerView != null) {
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
            mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(),
                    mRecyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                    switch (position) {
                       /* case 0:
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, OneActivity.class));
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TwoActivity.class));
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ThreeActivity.class));
                            break;*/
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {}
            }));
        }

        prepareObjects();

        Glide.with(this)
                .load(R.drawable.cover_backdrop)
                .into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop));
    }

    @Override
    protected void prepareObjects() {
        objectList.add(new YarObject("Bla-bla", 3.9, R.drawable.bla_bla));
        objectList.add(new YarObject("Bla-bla-bla", 3.5, R.drawable.bla-bla-bla));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_object_list, menu);
        final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_action);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        newText = newText.toLowerCase();
        ArrayList<YarObject> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (YarObject object : objectList) {
            String name = object.getName().toLowerCase();

            if (name.contains(newText)) {
                filteredList.add(object);
            }
        }

        adapter.setFilter(filteredList);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Если обрабатывать нажатие в методе `onClick()` для `RecyclerView`, то ничего не выходит потому что там задана фиксированная `position`
Пожалуйста,подскажите как можно это сделать.

Comment: Вам надо работать не с позицией элемента в списке но с данными. Т.е. в слушателе нажатия получите по позиции элемент списка отображаемых данных и в зависимости от его значения что-то делайте

Comment: Думал-думал над Вашим комментарием...Не могли бы Вы, пожалуйста, чуть подробнее объяснить?

Comment: Вопрос к автору вопроса. Вам получилось реализовать вашу идею? Если да, то поделитесь пожалуйста как.

Answer (score 0):

@Override
    public void onQueryInput(String query) {

```
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(query)) {
        refreshAdapter();//это кастомный метод где ты возвращаешь всё на исходные позиции
        return;
    }

    final String quer = lastQuery = query.toLowerCase();


    try {
        mExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final List<Unit> queryUnits = new ArrayList<>();
                final Map<Integer, List<Unit>> queryDataModel = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                        if (o1 < o2)
                            return 1;
                        return o2 < o1 ? -1 : 0;
                    }
                });

                for (Unit unit : mAllUnits //Это лист со всеми элементами, которые есть
                        ) {
                    if (StringScore.score(unit.getLocationTag(), quer) > 0.1 ||
                            StringScore.score(unit.getCameraName(), quer) > 0.1 ||
                            StringScore.score(unit.getLocaleMediaDate(), quer) > 0.1)
                        queryUnits.add(unit);
                }

                for (Unit unit : queryUnits
                        ) {
                    Integer key = unit.getSimpleIntegerKey();
                    if (queryDataModel.containsKey(key)) {
                        queryDataModel.get(key).add(unit);
                    } else {
                        queryDataModel.put(key, new ArrayList<Unit>());
                        queryDataModel.get(key).add(unit);
                    }
                }

                for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Unit>> entry : queryDataModel.entrySet()
                        ) {
                    Collections.sort(entry.getValue(), Unit.UNIT_COMPARATOR);
                }

                Collections.sort(queryUnits, Unit.UNIT_COMPARATOR);

                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (lastQuery.equals(quer)) {
                            mDataModel = queryDataModel;
                            mUnits = queryUnits; //Это лист, количество элементов котороe указано в getItemCount();
                            notifyDataSetChanged();//благодаря этому методу всё обновится
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: где я должен переопрделеить этот метод?

Comment: Там где приходит запрос с searchView,  я неизнаю какпя у тебя архитектура, но query в сигнатуре это то что вводится в searchView,   в методе интерфейся onQueryInputListener , или что-то похожее, тот код чтотя скинул он внутри адаптера находится.